# Using Async Function to return more results

Tags: javascript, java, asynchronous, velo

I have a dataset with 3000 rows in and in Wix builder. Wix has a limit of 1000 returns however they suggest a workaround here: https://www.wix.com/velo/forum/coding-with-velo/dataset-query-for-3000-items

I am trying to add this to my code however I don't know where it needs to be inserted, can someone please help me? My code is below:

```
import wixData from 'wix-data';

$w.onReady(function () {
    uniqueDropDown1();
});

function uniqueDropDown1 (){
    wixData.query("Products")
         .limit(1000) 
         .ascending("Manufacturer")
      .find()
      .then(results => {
           const uniqueTitles = getUniqueTitles(results.items); 
           $w("#dropdown1").options = buildOptions(uniqueTitles); 
      });
     function getUniqueTitles(items) {
     const titlesOnly = items.map(item => item.Manufacturer);
     return [...new Set(titlesOnly)];
    }
    function buildOptions(uniqueList) { 
        return uniqueList.map(curr => {
            return {label:curr, value:curr}; 
        });
    }
 }
 export function dropdown1_change(event) {
 uniqueDropDown2(); 
 $w("#dropdown2").enable();
 function uniqueDropDown2 (){
    wixData.query("Products")
        .contains("Manufacturer", $w("#dropdown1").value)
        .limit(1000) 
        .ascending("Model")
      .find()
      .then(results => {
           const uniqueTitles = getUniqueTitles(results.items); 
           $w("#dropdown2").options = buildOptions(uniqueTitles);
      });

  function getUniqueTitles(items) {
        const titlesOnly = items.map(item => item.Model);
     return [...new Set(titlesOnly)];
    }
    function buildOptions(uniqueList) { 
        return uniqueList.map(curr => {
            return {label:curr, value:curr}; 
        });
    }
}
}

export function dropdown2_change(event) {
    uniqueDropDown3(); 
    $w("#dropdown3").enable();
    function uniqueDropDown3 (){
    wixData.query("Products")
        .contains("Model", $w("#dropdown2").value)
        .limit(1000) 
        .ascending("Part")
      .find()
      .then(results => {
           const uniqueTitles = getUniqueTitles(results.items); 
           $w("#dropdown3").options = buildOptions(uniqueTitles); 
      });
}

  function getUniqueTitles(items) {
        const titlesOnly = items.map(item => item.Part);
     return [...new Set(titlesOnly)];
    }
    function buildOptions(uniqueList) { 
        return uniqueList.map(curr => {
            return {label:curr, value:curr}; 
        });
    }
}
```

and I think I need to somehow incorporate the following, but I have absolutely no idea how:

```
async function fetchData() {
const firstPage = await wixData.query('collection')
.limit(1000)
.find();

const secondPage = await wixData.query('collection')
.limit(1000)
.skip(1000)
.find();

const thirdPage = await wixData.query('collection')
.limit(1000)
.skip(2000)
.find();

const allItems = firstPage.items.concat(secondPage.items).concat(thirdPage.items);
  return allItems;
  }
```

thanks in advance for all your help. The dataset is called products and the columns are Manufacturer, Model and Part.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

I refactored the code to make use of a `findAll` function, that downloads all the items (inspired by `retrieveAllItems` found at [WixDataQuery API reference](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-data/wixdataquery/limit))

```
import wixData from 'wix-data';

$w.onReady(function () {
    uniqueDropDown1();
});

// New function. Downloads all items sequentially in batches of 1000
async function findAll(wixDataQuery) {
    let allItems = [];
    let results = await wixDataQuery.limit(1000).find();
    allItems.push(results.items);
    while (results.hasNext()) {
        results = await results.next();
        allItems.push(results.items);
    }
    return allItems;
}

function uniqueDropDown1() {
    // Changed this
    findAll(
        wixData.query("Products")
            .ascending("Manufacturer")
    ).then(results => {
        const uniqueTitles = getUniqueTitles(results);
        $w("#dropdown1").options = buildOptions(uniqueTitles);
    });

    function getUniqueTitles(items) {
        const titlesOnly = items.map(item => item.Manufacturer);
        return [...new Set(titlesOnly)];
    }
    function buildOptions(uniqueList) {
        return uniqueList.map(curr => {
            return { label: curr, value: curr };
        });
    }
}
export function dropdown1_change(event) {
    uniqueDropDown2();
    $w("#dropdown2").enable();
    function uniqueDropDown2() {
        // Changed this
        findAll(
            wixData.query("Products")
                .contains("Manufacturer", $w("#dropdown1").value)
                .ascending("Model")
        ).then(results => {
            const uniqueTitles = getUniqueTitles(results);
            $w("#dropdown2").options = buildOptions(uniqueTitles);
        });

        function getUniqueTitles(items) {
            const titlesOnly = items.map(item => item.Model);
            return [...new Set(titlesOnly)];
        }
        function buildOptions(uniqueList) {
            return uniqueList.map(curr => {
                return { label: curr, value: curr };
            });
        }
    }
}

export function dropdown2_change(event) {
    uniqueDropDown3();
    $w("#dropdown3").enable();
    function uniqueDropDown3() {
        // Changed this
        findAll(
            wixData.query("Products")
                .contains("Model", $w("#dropdown2").value)
                .ascending("Part")
        ).then(results => {
                const uniqueTitles = getUniqueTitles(results);
                $w("#dropdown3").options = buildOptions(uniqueTitles);
            });
    }

    function getUniqueTitles(items) {
        const titlesOnly = items.map(item => item.Part);
        return [...new Set(titlesOnly)];
    }
    function buildOptions(uniqueList) {
        return uniqueList.map(curr => {
            return { label: curr, value: curr };
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mal, 

Firstly thank you for coming back with a thorough answer, I am not a particularly technically minded person so your response was refreshing. :)

Unfortunately the code you sent returns no results in the top dropdown (so the others don't fire either), but the code doesn't give an error so the Syntax is correct I think. Do I need to put something in the WixDataQuery? 

Many Thanks, 
Oscar

Comment: It's hard for me to guess what's wrong, since I'm working on assumptions about your context. You could perhaps attempt to gradually move towards my solution to identify where the error occurs. Or you could append `console.log` statements in the code to get further information about what's happening.